# How to use a more complex query inside mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use a more complex query through PHP and seem to be having issues. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$result = mysql_query('select(select count(*) from tblname where column LIKE xyz) and      (select count(*) from tblname2 where column2='Value'));
```

This doesn't seem to work - any help?

Comment: This isn't a valid query in the 1st place.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?  "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid SQL. If you want the sum of both counts, maybe you mean:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tblname
    WHERE column LIKE xyz
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tblname2
    WHERE column2 = 'Value'
) x
```

Comment: The query I provided works fine. The query you're providing is not working as the intended function. It also doesn't describe how to fit a query that contains parenthesis within mysql_query()

Comment: @cbcp The query you provided should not work fine, and I don't know what you want to do with it honestly. To use a query that contains parentheses into `mysql_query`, just use the literal string as is, including parentheses. Parentheses do not cause `mysql_query` to fail.

Comment: When I attempt it however I get:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /root/test.php on line 9


$result = mysql_query("select (select count(*) from tblclients where datecreated LIKE '2012-12-%') and (select count(*) from tblcustomfieldsvalues where value="Google.com")");
if (!$result) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_result($result);

Answer (score 0):

You're using incorrect syntax, did you try to check the manual first?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: How is this incorrect? It works just fine.

    mysql> select (select count(*) from tblclients where datecreated LIKE '2012-12-%') and (select count(*) from tblcustomfieldsvalues where value="Google.com");

| (select count(*) from tblclients where datecreated LIKE '2012-12-%') and (select count(*) from tblcustomfieldsvalues where value="Google.com") |
                                                                                                                                            1 |